# Reducing template bloat with inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, templates, code-generation

Does anyone have experience reducing template code bloat through inheritance?

I hesitate rewriting our containers this way:

```
class vectorBase
{
  public:
    int size();
    void clear();
    int m_size;
    void *m_rawData;
    //....
};

template< typename T > 
class vector : public vectorBase
{
    void push_back( const T& );
    //...

};
```

I should keep maximum performance while reducing compile time. I'm also wondering why Standard Library implementations do not uses this approach.

Comment: This code does not work as it is, since all `vectorBase` members are `private`, thus inaccessible from derived classes.

Comment: And it's missing `;` everywhere but we got the point. +1 Interesting question imho.

Comment: yeah i know this code won't compile. i don't care;) I don't want to paste a entire stl containers...

Comment: Interesting question. I would guess, that most of the time, this optimization does not help at all. But I really would have to try and benchmark (code size/time) the result.

Comment: Template bloat is not a real problem: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771692/when-does-template-instantiation-bloat-matter-in-practice

Comment: @Martin: That's plain wrong. At linktime the compiler do removes duplicates, but a compile time you can have gigabytes of temp obj reducing compile and link time.

Comment: @benoitj: I woyld disagree (especially since each compiler does it differently and some) PS it's not objects but repeated implementation of methods that is causing the code bloat, and your method does not solve this in any way, so as I suggested in the previous article coda bloat is not a technical issue but rather a mental agility problem. If you can provide some HARD figures that show that your technique makes the code that uses you technique faster to compile (ie build a version of the STL using this technique) and compile a general app against it then I may reconsider.

Comment: @benoitj: statements like "should keep maximum performance while reducing compile time" are highly suspect. You state like a fact without providing any proof other than "it is obvious". If it was a fact you would have provided data? Yet with modern compilers and all the techniques they use to increase performance you think they don't already optimize away this theoretical problem (it may have been a problem in 1995 but not any longer)

Comment: @Martin: 1) check my answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771692/when-does-template-instantiation-bloat-matter-in-practice/3038020#3038020 . "Mental agility problem" ??? Template bloat can WASTE your time. 2) I'm not saying my technique will provide some compile time gain. I 'm just wondering if someone tried it

Comment: Sorry about the mental agility, badly cut and paste using my mind(no agility there) rather than a computer.

Answer (score 3):

Only very few operations on a vector make sense if you don't know what type the stored elements are. For example the `clear()` method you added to your base class needs to call the destructors of the elements removed from the vector, so it needs to know their type and needs to be templated.

There is also really not much you can do with the a `void *m_rawData` without knowing the types of the things inside it, basically all operations on it at least have to know the size of the stored type. The only thing I can think of would be that you can `free()` it if you know that it contains no elements (if it contains elements you have to call their destructors). Allocating, setting and accessing elements all doesn't work if you don't know where the individual elements start and end. Also the implementation of all the methods would be much cleaner and simpler if `m_rawData` would be a properly typed `T*` instead.

A `size()` method in the base class would only work if its only job is to return a `m_size` member variable, but a vector doesn't necessarily have to store the size explicitly (the implementations I know of don't). You could probably implement is so that the size is stored explicitly, but then again `size()` is probably not a method that takes long to compile, even if it's templated.

All together I don't think there are a lot of methods remaining, that are implementable in a base class. Most operation on a vector need to know about the elements stored in it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a premature optimization. In general except in embedded systems, disk space and memory are plentiful and cheap, so there's no reason to try to optimize for a small amount of code space. By keeping it all in the template code it makes it more obvious what's going on rather than using inheritance which would complicate things.

Additionally most applications aren't going to be generating hundreds of instantiations, and for each T not all methods may be used, reducing the code footprint further.

Only if there were extremely tight memory considerations (embedded) would I consider different possible approaches (including the one you presented).

EDIT: I'm not sure that there's much gain to be had in a little of standard container cases since they still need a lot of template code. For internal classes that have only a small amount of template-specific code and lots of common logic this could definitely help both generated code and compilation speed. I suspect it isn't used often because it's more complex and the benefits are restricted to certain scenarios.

Comment: He's talking about reducing _compile time._

Comment: @Stephen: Which is exactly what won't happen using this approach.  Most of the complexity in a container is in calling constructors and destructors at the appropriate times, and this can only be done in template code where the contained type is fully defined.

Comment: @Ben voigt: With this approach the in-place ctor / dtor calls are of course in the template code. But i can put in the base class the memory allocation / destruction  for exemple

Comment: @Ben Voigt: so you're saying that compiling the `T` constructor dwarfs the repeated compilation of the rbtree in `map`?

Comment: @benoitj: the destructors won't be called in `vectorBase::clear()` because the compiler doesn't know the type of the objects in the array in `vectorBase`, and in fact thinks they're of a type that doesn't have a destructor.

Comment: @Stephen: I'm saying that the compiler effort to parse the several dozen functions in `map` which call `T`'s constructor or destructor or user-defined `operator=` is likely the bulk of the time.  To be any more specific than that, we have to talk about a particular vendor's implementation of `<map>` and version of the source code.

Comment: @Ben. Voigt: yes... that is where this question is interesting.  I think that's @benoitj's whole point of asking it.  At what complexity does the scale tip?

Comment: @Stephen The very first sentence of the question led me to believe he was worried about generated code bloat from templates, and keeping compile time *no worse* than with a straight template implementation.

Comment: @Mark B: true :) I guess i thought it focused more on reducing bloat as a means of reducing compile time.

Comment: It does focus on reducing compile time;)

Answer (score 1):

I understand your approach.

To be frank I have used it... although obviously not for STL containers: their code is virtually bug-free and optimized and I am highly unlikely to come up with a better implementation on my own!

I don't care much about compile-time: it's an embarrassingly parallel problem (apart from link) and `distcc` etc take care of all the troubles you can have even with a large codebase. And I mean large, I work at a company which required a new compiler from HP because the version we had didn't not support more than 128Ko... in the command line of the linker. And it was only one of the application, and it was a few years ago, and they thankfully splitted it up in several chunks since.

However, as much as I don't care about compile-time, I *do* care a lot about reduced dependencies and binary compatibility. And thus when I write templated code of my own I do check if it's possible to factor some operations outside of the templated code.

The first task is to isolate those point where you can really gain. Getting one line of code out is not worth your time, you want to get full functions.

The second task is to decide whether or not you wish to keep them inlined. It depends whether or not you care about performance, the overhead of a function call may or may not be important to you.

However I would certainly not use inheritance for the job. `Inheritance` is a `IS-A` relationship: it defines an interface, not an implementation. Either use `Composition` or simply free functions that you stash in a utility namespace (`detail` like in Boost ?).

Answer (score 1):

Some implementations **do** use (a form of) the above approach. Here is GCC's

```
  template<typename _Tp, typename _Alloc = std::allocator<_Tp> >
    class vector : protected _Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>
    {
    ... 
    }
```

In this case, the goal is to delegate memory management to `_Vector_base`. If you do choose to spend your time reinventing STL, please follow up here with your results. Perhaps your efforts will help put an end to the old "code bloat" cries still heard from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, Qt uses (or used?) a similar approach for their QList et al.

Basically, it would work, but you have to make sure you put everything that depends on `T` inside vector template. Unfortunately, that is almost all code there is in the vector class (in many cases, the code needs to call some `T` constructor or destructor), except for allocating raw storage and `size()`/`capacity()`. I'm not sure that it pays off, so double-check.

It does certainly pay of when you can abstract away from some template parameter (eg. `set<T>::iterator` need not be aware of the set's comparator) or if you can brew a full implementation for a large class of types (eg. with trivial copy-ctor and dtor).

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted is just plain wrong. If the class you're storing in the vector has a destructor, that destructor won't be called, because the compiler `vectorBase` has lost all information about when to call the destructor by casting to `void*`.

To do this properly, calling the right destructor, you need to generate different copies of the code that each call the right destructor, and this work is simplified by using templates.

(To use your approach with a non-template base class, you need to generate just as much machine code, but you need to write a whole lot more C++ code by hand.)

That's why this approach really isn't worthwhile.

Comment: Yeah i know my code is wrong. That's not really important. I'm just showing the idea of "extracting" as much as possible template code in  a base class. You're right for dtor/ctor, but for exemple i could put the malloc / free in the base class

Answer (score 0):

*The short of it:*

Yes, this approach will [probably] work in limited, specialized circumstances.  I don't suspect `std::vector` (or the rest of STL) to be among those circumstances.

*The long of it:*

As others have mentioned (and I agree), outside of an embedded system, code bloat isn't much of a problem on a compiled binary.

But, many of us suffer the compilation cost of building magnitudes more code during the compilation step than we might if there were compiled libraries to link against (instead of compiling header files).  Add to it the difficulty of changing one of those templated header files and watch your entire project recompile from scratch.  Long compile times make for sad developers :(

It may not affect a large percent of developers - depending on the size of your company's codebase, and how you structure your build environment.  It certainly taxes us at my company.

As some answers have pointed out, there isn't much to abstract from a `std::vector` that would make it fair any better in your example.  Certainly you need to be able to create and destroy individual elements, and making any methods `virtual` would hinder run-time performance (which is more important than compile-time performance).  In addition, the compiler will lose the ability to optimize the `void*` library for templated code, this could result in a large performance loss.

I'm more interested in the more complex structures - would `std::map` benefit from abstraction?  What if you took the red-black tree (the SGI implementation) out and linked against a red-black tree library.  You would (probably) need to store the elements outside of the `std::map`, so it doesn't need to call the destructors, but that might (again) cause a run-time performance loss due to doubling your indirection.

I'm fairly certain that you couldn't use this method to improve on STL's implementation.

If you had better knowledge of the data structures you were storing, or you had a very specific templated type (not necessarily a container), you could probably improve your performance.  But, then the question becomes - how often will you use this new templated type such that the overhead of compiling it will be noticeably improved?  Certainly it would help compile times for `std::vector`, but maybe not for `my_domain_specific_ptr_container`.  If you save 50% of compile time for `my_domain_specific_ptr_container`, how many times would you have to use it to notice a significant enough build boost to justify the added complexity to the class (and reduced debug ability).

If you haven't already, your time may be better spent distributing your build tools :)

If, on the other hand, you try this and it works for STL containers... please post back.  I want a faster build! ;)