# Heavy use of templates for mobile platforms

Tags: c++, templates, mobile

I've been flicking through the book Modern C++ Design by Andrei Alexandrescu and it seems interesting stuff. However it makes very extensive use of templates and I would like to find out if this should be avoided if using C++ for mobile platform development (Brew MP, WebOS, iOS etc.) due to size considerations.

In Symbian OS C++ the standard use of templates is discouraged, the Symbian OS itself uses them but using an idiom known as thin templates where the underlying implementation is done in a C style using void* pointers with a thin template layered on top of this to achieve type safety. 
The reason they use this idiom as opposed to regular use of templates is specifically to avoid code bloating.

So what are opinions (or facts) on the use of templates when developing applications for mobile platforms.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When does template instantiation bloat matter in practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771692/when-does-template-instantiation-bloat-matter-in-practice)

Comment: +1, I didn't know thin templates.

Comment: even on mobile devices, exe size will mean nothing compared to other media like images, text, sounds. as always, profile first and do not prematurely optimize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my personal experience using (and even abusing) templates very rarely result in large code bloat, and compiling with `-Os` will help a lot.

It's not that common to see huge template classes duplicated (instantiated) many times, both because rarely classes are *huge*, and because in most cases you only instantiate templates with a few different arguments, not hundreds. Besides it's easy to reuse some common code in your biggest template classes/functions, and compiler will help you in doing this.

Usually size of data (graphics, audio, ...) is orders of magnitude bigger than the code. So I wouldn't worry.

Of course there could be exceptions to what I said, but I guess they'll mostly be about *advanced* (*special* / *weird* / *complicated*) stuff, not with the most common everyday classes.

Summarizing my suggestion: use templates as much as you want, if something will go wrong you'll find that out by profiling, and you will easily be able to optimize the size.

Answer (score 9):

Go ahead and use templates wherever they make your code easier to understand and to maintain.  Avoidance of templates on mobile platforms can be categorized as "premature optimization".

If you run into executable-size issues, then redesign if necessary, but don't start with the assumption that templates will cause problems before you see any actual problems.

A lot of the stuff in "Modern C++ Design" and similar books is not going to lead to bloated code, because so much of it is really designed to ensure type safety and do compile-time metaprogramming magic, rather than to generate code.

Templates can be used to do a lot of different things.  They can generate more code than you expect, but that's not a reason to ban their use.  It wasn't so long ago that various authorities recommended avoiding exceptions, virtual functions, floating-point math, and even classes due to concerns about code size and performance, but people did those things, and somehow everything worked out fine.

Comment: agree. when a templated approach is best, use it. if it leads to huge binary size, there are ways to refactor to reduce it

Comment: CLang may be helpful as well, I think they have a number of mobile targets by now, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Templates don't necessarily lead to code bloat. If you write a function or class template and instantiate it for a dozen different types then yes, you get a lot of duplicate code generated (probably, anyway. Some compilers can merge identical instantiations back together).

But if a template is instantiated for one type only, then there is *zero* cost in code size. If you instantiate it a couple of times, you pay a certain cost, but you'd also end up paying if you used any of the other ways to achieve the same thing. Dynamic polymorphism (virtual functions and inheritance) isn't free either. You pay for that in terms of vtables, code generated to facilitate all the type casts and conversions necessary, and simply because of code that can't be inlined or optimized away.

Taking `std::vector` as an example, then yes, if you use both `vector<int>` and `vector<float>`, you get two copies of *some* of the code. But with templates, only the code that is actually *used* gets compiled. The member functions that you never call won't generate any code, and even in the functions that *are* compiled, the compiler may be able to eliminate a lot of code. For example, for certain types, exception handling code may be unnecessary, so the compiler can eliminate it, yielding *smaller* code than if you'd used dynamic polymorphism, where the compiler would've been unable to make *any* assumptions about the type being stored. So in this made-up example, you'd get *some* code generated for both `vector<int>` and `vector<float>`, but each of them is going to be a lot smaller than a polymorphic vector as you might find in Java, for example.

The main problem with using templates is that it requires a compiler which supports it. On a PC, that's no problem. On any other platform which has a mature C++ compiler available, it's no problem.

But not all platforms have a modern heavy-duty C++ compiler available. Some don't support a number of advanced features, and some are just not good enough at the optimizations required to make template code work (templates tend to require a lot of inlining, for example). So on some platforms, it may be best to avoid templates. Not because of any concern for code size, but because the compiler may be unable to handle it.

Comment: This really is the http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SufficientlySmartCompiler syndrome. There are a lot of very smart C++ techniques that require a Sufficiently Smart Compiler. But in the embedded field, such compilers are really rare. Usually they just do what you tell it to do - which in many cases is to generate a big heap of bloated code.

Comment: If I can rephrase that - there are very many compiler optimizations that *may* happen - and a lot of smart C++ techniques that assume that such optimizations do happen. Just to name one such technique - return value optimization. If they encounter a compiler that don't do this optimization, the code will suddenly perform really bad. Code elimination that doesn't happen can be an even worse problem for templates.

Comment: except in this case we're not talking about "code elimination that doesn't happen", but about "code that is never generated in the first place". The standard guarantees that templates aren't instantiated until you instantiate them. A compiler which tried to instantiate template code that wasn't called (say, every function in a class template, instead of just the ones that are used) might encounter compilation errors and reject your perfectly valid C++ program. It would be an error for a compiler to generate code for templates that are never instantiated.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever you do, do NOT try writing some code, compile it, and compare executable size or code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that generally (not just related to mobile development) this advice holds. Some of the techniques described in Modern C++ Design can lead to long build times and code bloat.

This is especially true when dealing with "obscure" devices, like cell phones. Many template techniques rely on that the compiler and linker do a perfect job in eliminating unused/duplicate code. If they don't, you risk having hundreds of duplicate `std::vector` instances scattered all over your code. And trust me, I have seen this happen.

This is not to say Modern C++ Design is a bad book, or that templates are bad. But especially on embedded projects it's best to watch out, because it can bite.

Comment: On a side note, can anybody recommend any 'similar' C++ books to this one which aren't so heavy on the use of templates? (I already have effective C++).

Comment: You mean a book about using templates to create generic versions of several common design patterns that doesn't use templates heavily?

Comment: Template metaprogramming scares the bejayzus out of me, but "C++ Coding Standards" is a great book by Sutter and Alexandrescu.